# How to diagonally subtract different columns in R

Tags: r, dataframe, multiple-columns, subtraction

I have a dataset of a hypothetical exam.

```
id <- c(1,1,3,4,5,6,7,7,8,9,9)
test_date <- c("2012-06-27","2012-07-10","2013-07-04","2012-03-24","2012-07-22", "2013-09-16","2012-06-21","2013-10-18", "2013-04-21", "2012-02-16", "2012-03-15")
result_date <- c("2012-07-29","2012-09-02","2013-08-01","2012-04-25","2012-09-01","2013-10-20","2012-07-01","2013-10-31", "2013-05-17", "2012-03-17", "2012-04-20")

data1 <- as_data_frame(id)
data1$test_date <- test_date
data1$result_date <- result_date

colnames(data1)[1] <- "id"
```

"id" indicates the ID of the students who have taken a particular exam. "test_date" is the date the students took the test and "result_date" is the date when the students' results are posted. I'm interested in finding out which students retook the exam BEFORE the result of that exam session was released, e.g. students who knew that they have underperformed and retook the exam without bothering to find out their scores. For example, student with "id" 1 took the exam for the second time on "2012-07-10" which was before the result date for his first exam - "2012-07-29".

I tried to:

```
data1%>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  arrange(id, test_date) %>%
  filter(n() >= 2) %>% #To only get info on students who have taken the exam more than once and then merge it back in with the original data set using a join function
```

So essentially, I want to create a new column called "re_test" where it would equal 1 if a student retook the exam BEFORE receiving the result of a previous exam and 0 otherwise (those who retook after seeing their marks or those who did not retake).

I have tried to mutate in order to find cases where dates are either positive or negative by subtracting the 2nd test_date from the 1st result_date:

```
mutate(data1, re_test = result_date - lead(test_date, default = first(test_date)))
```

However, this leads to mixing up students with different id's. I tried to split but mutate won't work on a list of dataframes so now I'm stuck:

```
split(data1, data1$id)
```

Just to add on, this is a part of the desired result:

```
  data2 <- as_data_frame(id <- c(1,1,3,4))
    data2$test_date_result <- c("2012-06-27","2012-07-10", "2013-07-04","2012-03-24")
    data2$result_date_result <- c("2012-07-29","2012-09-02","2013-08-01","2012-04-25")
    data2$re_test <- c(1, 0, 0, 0)
```

Apologies for the verbosity and hope I was clear enough.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 library(reshape2)
library(dplyr)

# first melt so that we can sequence by date 
data1m <- data1 %>% 
  melt(id.vars = "id", measure.vars = c("test_date", "result_date"), value.name = "event_date")

# any two tests in a row is a flag - use dplyr::lag to comapre the previous  
data1mc <- data1m %>%
  arrange(id, event_date) %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate (multi_test = (variable == "test_date" & lag(variable == "test_date"))) %>%
  filter(multi_test)

#      id  variable event_date multi_test
# 1     1 test_date 2012-07-10       TRUE
# 2     9 test_date 2012-03-15       TRUE

## join back to the original
data1 %>% 
  left_join (data1mc %>% select(id, event_date, multi_test), 
             by=c("id" = "id", "test_date" = "event_date"))
```

Comment: I actually made a slight error so I had to change the "lag" to a "lead". Result shouldn't have been " data2$re_test <- c(0, 1, 0, 0)" but rather " data2$re_test <- c(1, 0, 0, 0)"

Answer (score 0):

I have a piecewise answer that may work for you. I first create a data.frame called `student` that contains the re-test information, and then join it with the `data1` object. If students re-took the test multiple times, it will compare the last test to the first, which is a flaw, but I'm unsure if students have the ability to re-test multiple times?

```
student <- data1 %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  summarise(retest=(test_date[length(test_date)] < result_date[1]) == TRUE)
```

Some re-test values were NA. These were individuals that only took the test once. I set these to FALSE here, but you can retain the NA, as they do contain information.

```
student$retest[is.na(student$retest)] <- FALSE
```

Join the two data.frames to a single object called `data2`.

```
data2 <- left_join(data1, student, by='id')
```

Answer (score 0):

I went with a simple shift comparison. 1 line of code.

```
data1 <- data.frame(id = c(1,1,3,4,5,6,7,7,8,9,9), test_date = c("2012-06-27","2012-07-10","2013-07-04","2012-03-24","2012-07-22", "2013-09-16","2012-06-21","2013-10-18", "2013-04-21", "2012-02-16", "2012-03-15"), result_date = c("2012-07-29","2012-09-02","2013-08-01","2012-04-25","2012-09-01","2013-10-20","2012-07-01","2013-10-31", "2013-05-17", "2012-03-17", "2012-04-20"))

data1$re_test <- unlist(lapply(split(data1,data1$id), function(x) 
  ifelse(as.Date(x$test_date) > c(NA, as.Date(x$result_date[-nrow(x)])), 0, 1)))

data1
   id  test_date result_date re_test
1   1 2012-06-27  2012-07-29      NA
2   1 2012-07-10  2012-09-02       1
3   3 2013-07-04  2013-08-01      NA
4   4 2012-03-24  2012-04-25      NA
5   5 2012-07-22  2012-09-01      NA
6   6 2013-09-16  2013-10-20      NA
7   7 2012-06-21  2012-07-01      NA
8   7 2013-10-18  2013-10-31       0
9   8 2013-04-21  2013-05-17      NA
10  9 2012-02-16  2012-03-17      NA
11  9 2012-03-15  2012-04-20       1
```

I think there is benefit in leaving NAs but if you really want all others as zero, simply:

```
data1$re_test <- ifelse(is.na(data1$re_test), 0, data1$re_test)
data1
   id  test_date result_date re_test
1   1 2012-06-27  2012-07-29       0
2   1 2012-07-10  2012-09-02       1
3   3 2013-07-04  2013-08-01       0
4   4 2012-03-24  2012-04-25       0
5   5 2012-07-22  2012-09-01       0
6   6 2013-09-16  2013-10-20       0
7   7 2012-06-21  2012-07-01       0
8   7 2013-10-18  2013-10-31       0
9   8 2013-04-21  2013-05-17       0
10  9 2012-02-16  2012-03-17       0
11  9 2012-03-15  2012-04-20       1
```

Let me know if you have any questions, cheers.

Comment: id = 7 is not a re-test. id = 1  and id = 9 are re-tests , by my understanding of the question. Perhaps the 1, 0 in the ifelse should be reversed.

Comment: Did you mean id=8? And thanks I have edited the post to reflect that!

Answer (score 0):

I am sure there are more elegant ways to approach this. I did this by taking advantage of the structure of your data (sorted by id) and the lag function that can refer to the previous records while dealing with a current record.

```
### Ensure Data are sorted by ID ###
  data1 <- arrange(data1,id)
### Create Flag for those that repeated ###
  data1$repeater <- ifelse(lag(data1$id) == data1$id,1,0)
### I chose to do this on all data, you could filter on repeater flag first ###
  data1$timegap <- as.Date(data1$result_date) - as.Date(data1$test_date)
  data1$lagdate <- as.Date(data1$test_date) - lag(as.Date(data1$result_date))
### Display results where your repeater flag is 1 and there is negative time lag ###
  data1[data1$repeater==1 & !is.na(data1$repeater) & as.numeric(data1$lagdate) < 0,]

# A tibble: 2 × 6
     id  test_date result_date repeater timegap  lagdate
  <dbl>      <chr>       <chr>    <dbl>  <time>   <time>
1     1 2012-07-10  2012-09-02        1 54 days -19 days
2     9 2012-03-15  2012-04-20        1 36 days  -2 days
```